# Outlook user-properties are not getting deleted

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, custom-properties

I wrote following code to delete all the user properties of all the mails in folder -inbox. When I was stepping through the code, there were no any exceptions. Delete() and Save() methods were executed properly.

Then after, when I was checking for user properties using the outlook design mode still I was able to see the user property, it had not deleted. (see the picture)

[image]

Can you please explain what's going on here? Any mistakes in the code?

```
            //Test
            InboxFolder = outlookNs.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            items = InboxFolder.Items;
            foreach (object mailitem in items)
            {
                olMail = mailitem as Outlook.MailItem;
                if (olMail != null)
                {
                    Outlook.UserProperty upK = olMail.UserProperties["Processed"];
                    if (upK != null)
                        upK.Delete();
                    olMail.Save();
                }
            }
            //Test
```

Comment: Do you still see the properties after running the code and then restarting Outlook?

Comment: Yes, but I have done the same thing in (not the exact same code, but the concept) it had worked to me. I can't why it behaves unusually in this scenario :-( Thanks Dmitry.